# Is there an algorithm for finding a day of a week (Sunday, Monday, etc.)?

Tags: c

Is there an algorithm for finding a day of a week (Sunday, Monday, etc.) with a date (day and month, **no year**), while using only the starting day of the year (1.1 will be: Sunday, Monday...)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest algorithm to find the day of week of day zero of a given year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478694/what-is-the-easiest-algorithm-to-find-the-day-of-week-of-day-zero-of-a-given-yea)

Comment: You.will need to know the year to accurately find any day after Feb 28.

Comment: Given month M and day D, sum the days for all months before M. Then add `D-1` to get the total number of days since Jan 1. Then compute `total%7 + 1` and that gives you the day of the week, where 1=Sun, 2=Mon, etc. For example, given March 10, we have `sum=31+28` and `total=sum+10-1=68`. So `weekday=68%7+1=6` which is Friday. Look at the calendar for 2023, and you'll see that Jan 6 and March 10 are both Fridays. (Note: as Mark already mentioned, summing the days for the early months is problematic because February has 28 or 29 days, depending on the year.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week What research did you do?

Comment: Can you agree with whoever gave you this to do, that first day of the year (1.1) is March 1st? Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an algorithm for finding a day of a week ... with a date (day and month, **no** year) while using only the starting day of the year ... **

Yes for first 2 months.  Hint: begin with `(starting_day + 31*(Month==Feb) + day)%7`.

No, for days   March 1st or later.  Code needs to know if the year is a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is:

1. Make a function like `int sumDaysOfMyDate( int date[2] );` which contains an array like `int daysInMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31...};` to calculate the sum of the days up to the given date. (I supposed the date is stored in an array of 2 ints: one for the day and one for the month)
2. Take the moduluo 7 of the sum and use it as index for the array `char *days[7] = {"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"...};`. And that's it.

To help you visualize

```
printf("%s\n", days[sumDaysOfMyDate(date)%7]);
```

All of that supposing that the 1st January is Sunday, as I guessed from this part of your question: *"1.1 will be: Sunday, Monday...)"*; and supposing that February has 28 days.